# How can I make IntelliJ order javascript object properties by name in the watch window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am debugging a javascript application. Please, observe a snapshot of the watch window:

[image]

Note, that the properties are displayed in what appears a total mess. It is probably their natural order, but when there are lots of them it becomes really annoying. Is it possible to order them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just press 'Sort values alphabetically' button:

[image]